# How to do manual transaction management with JOOQ and Spring-boot 2.0?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, java-8, jooq

Using Spring Boot 2.0.4 and JOOQ 3.11.3.

I have a server endpoint that needs fine-grained control over transaction management; it needs to issue multiple SQL statements before and after an external call and must not keep the DB transaction open while talking to the external site.

In the below code `testTransactionV4` is the attempt I like best.

I've looked in the JOOQ manual but the transaction-management section is pretty light-on and seems to imply this is the way to do it.

It feels like I'm working harder than I should be here, which is usually a sign that I'm doing it wrong.  Is there a better, "correct" way to do manual transaction management with Spring/JOOQ?

Also, any improvements to the implementation of the TransactionBean would be greatly appreciated (and upvoted).

But the point of this question is really just: "Is this the right way"?

---

TestEndpoint:

```
@Role.SystemApi
@SystemApiEndpoint
public class TestEndpoint {
  private static Log log = to(TestEndpoint.class);

  @Autowired private DSLContext db;
  @Autowired private TransactionBean txBean;
  @Autowired private Tx tx;

  private void doNonTransactionalThing() {
    log.info("long running thing that should not be inside a transaction");
  }

  /** Works; don't like the commitWithResult name but it'll do if there's
   no better way.  Implementation is ugly too.
   */
  @JsonPostMethod("testTransactionV4")
  public void testMultiTransactionWithTxBean() {
    log.info("start testMultiTransactionWithTxBean");

    AccountRecord account = txBean.commitWithResult( db ->
      db.fetchOne(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT.ID.eq(1)) );

    doNonTransactionalThing();

    account.setName("test_tx+"+new Date());

    txBean.commit(db -> account.store() );
  }

  /** Works; but it's ugly, especially having to work around lambda final
   requirements on references.   */
  @JsonPostMethod("testTransactionV3")
  public void testMultiTransactionWithJooqApi() {
    log.info("start testMultiTransactionWithJooqApi");

    AtomicReference<AccountRecord> account = new AtomicReference<>();
    db.transaction( config->
      account.set(DSL.using(config).fetchOne(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT.ID.eq(1))) );

    doNonTransactionalThing();

    account.get().setName("test_tx+"+new Date());

    db.transaction(config->{
      account.get().store();
    });
  }

  /** Does not work, there's only one commit that spans over the long operation */
  @JsonPostMethod("testTransactionV1")
  @Transactional
  public void testIncorrectSingleTransactionWithMethodAnnotation() {
    log.info("start testIncorrectSingleTransactionWithMethodAnnotation");

    AccountRecord account = db.fetchOne(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT.ID.eq(1));

    doNonTransactionalThing();

    account.setName("test_tx+"+new Date());
    account.store();
  }

  /** Works, but I don't like defining my tx boundaries this way, readability
   is poor (relies on correct bean naming and even then is non-obvious) and is
   fragile in the face of refactoring.  When explicit TX boundaries are needed
   I want them getting in my face straight away.
   */
  @JsonPostMethod("testTransactionV2")
  public void testMultiTransactionWithNestedComponent() {
    log.info("start testTransactionWithComponentDelegation");

    AccountRecord account = tx.readAccount();

    doNonTransactionalThing();

    account.setName("test_tx+"+new Date());
    tx.writeAccount(account);
  }

  @Component
  static class Tx {
    @Autowired private DSLContext db;

    @Transactional
    public AccountRecord readAccount() {
      return db.fetchOne(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT.ID.eq(1));
    }

    @Transactional
    public void writeAccount(AccountRecord account) {
      account.store();
    }
  }

}
```

TransactionBean:

```
@Component
public class TransactionBean {
  @Autowired private DSLContext db;

  /**
   Don't like the name, but can't figure out how to make it be just "commit".
   */
  public <T> T commitWithResult(Function<DSLContext, T> worker) {
    // Yuck, at the very least need an array or something as the holder.
    AtomicReference<T> result = new AtomicReference<>();
    db.transaction( config -> result.set(
      worker.apply(DSL.using(config))
    ));
    return result.get();
  }

  public void commit(Consumer<DSLContext> worker) {
    db.transaction( config ->
      worker.accept(DSL.using(config))
    );
  }

  public void commit(Runnable worker) {
    db.transaction( config ->
      worker.run()
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just us springs `TransactionTemplate` instead of trying to implement your own. Wrap the part that needs to be transactional with it. For JOOQ it still seems like a spring managed transaction so that doesn't need to change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) to wrap the transactional part. Spring Boot provides one out-of-the-box so it is ready for use. You can use the [`execute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionCallback-)  method to wrap a call in a transaction.

```
@Autowired
private TransactionTemplate transaction;

@JsonPostMethod("testTransactionV1")
public void testIncorrectSingleTransactionWithTransactionTemplate() {
  log.info("start testIncorrectSingleTransactionWithMethodAnnotation");

  AccountRecord account = transaction.execute( status -> db.fetchOne(ACCOUNT, ACCOUNT.ID.eq(1)));

  doNonTransactionalThing();

  transaction.execute(status -> {
    account.setName("test_tx+"+new Date());
    account.store();
    return null;
  }
}
```

Something like that should do the trick. Not sure if the lambdas would work (keep forgetting the syntax of the [`TransactionCallback`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionCallback.html)